# Getting error when installing cdqa on my Windows 10

Tags: python, bert-language-model

when I am trying to install cdqa on my jupyter notebook, using !pip install cdqa, it is showing an error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cdqa (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cdqa
Any help regarding this will be helpful

[You can check details below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSFS5.png)

Comment: No, the installation is giving error too

Comment: What error? The link tells you can’t install it with pip. The linked answer and the package’s repository gives you the alternate installation instructions. If you are getting another error, please specify.

Comment: Thanks, I created a venv with python 3.8 and installed miscrosoft visual code for c++ it worked